# Pandas converting two columns to datetime throws continously errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, types

I am having a dataframe containing a column with the date (e.g. `01.01.2006`) and a column with the time (e.g. `16:00`). I am trying for 2 hours now to merge the 2 into a single column `datetime`. The format of `datetime` should be just anything that indicates the day and time, e.g. `16:00-01.01.2006`. A minimal version of the dataframe can look like this:

```
array([['01.01.2006', '01:00', 121.82],
       ['01.01.2006', '02:00', 120.78],
       ['01.01.2006', '03:00', 112.51],
       ['01.01.2006', '04:00', 100.63],
       ['01.01.2006', '05:00', 66.11]], dtype=object)
```

I have tried a dozen of options the latest:

```
df['datetime'] = df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['datetime']], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

resulting in an error in the 2nd line:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

1.) What am I doing wrong above?

2.) Is there a shorter way to convert the 2 columns straight away into the desired `datetime`? Tnx

Comment: Try single bracket `pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')`

Comment: @QuangHoang OMG, I suspected I made a stupid mistake like that. You are right, this solved it. If you wish make the comment an answer and I will accept it as an answer to my question. If you wish you could also explain how to turn the 2 columns to datetime with just 1 line of code, in case you know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ,I did not see the answer of Quand Hoang, in case you are interested:

```
df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(" ".join(row[["date", "time"]])), axis=1)
```

Comment: I was looking for how to use `.apply`, but I didn't know you can that easily work with `row`

Comment: maybe you could have a look at the `axis` parameter of apply

Comment: if the answer suites your needs, can you validate it, thx?

Comment: Sure, I just waited if QuangHong would post a full answer :)